# Pyspark- transform rows and columns of excel file using python or pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have files(xlsx) which contain data like agent name and its data, then agent name and its data.

Example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I add a column which will contain the agent names in all the columns which have its data? I want to create a dataframe and calculate kpis.

Expected output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your expected output and the code you've tried

Comment: Do you mind sharing the dataframe sample or the `.xlsx`?

Comment: Can i get your mail id or anything else so that i can share. As its not safe to share here.

Comment: Upload it to a file sharing website and post the link here

Comment: Please find the file here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d6e7d0577384d532b336663b2b39a58e20210914115201/390271

Comment: Hi @Luke, Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

We can add the name to the columns in the below format to the respective cells.

```
import openpyxl
from copy import copy
path = "C:/Users/Python/TestData.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 
sheet_obj = wb.active
Name = sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
#NameFont = sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 1)
sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 8).value = "Name"
sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 1)._style)
sheet_obj['H3'] = Name.value
sheet_obj.cell(row = 3, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 3, column = 1)._style)
sheet_obj['H4'] = Name.value
sheet_obj.cell(row = 4, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 4, column = 1)._style)
sheet_obj['H5'] = Name.value
sheet_obj.cell(row = 5, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 5, column = 1)._style)
sheet_obj['H6'] = Name.value
sheet_obj.cell(row = 6, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 6, column = 1)._style)
sheet_obj['H7'] = Name.value
sheet_obj.cell(row = 7, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 7, column = 1)._style)
sheet_obj['H8'] = Name.value
sheet_obj.cell(row = 8, column = 8)._style = copy(sheet_obj.cell(row = 8, column = 1)._style)
wb.save(path)
```

Below is the output:

[image]

Keep this in a loop if we want to apply this for entire excel sheet, this can be done based on the name.